# How to configure Winedt 10.3 to use SumatraPDF

Tags: winedt, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

This has become impossible.

The advice on the forums is to use magnifying glass in Execution Modes -Pdf viewer and then navigate to C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF

but SumatraPDF is not there, it is hidden  somewhere.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your issue better, for example show the used path, show a configuration screenshot etc.

Comment: I am referring to the advice at https://gist.github.com/rkitover/b4c75fc2eb4e245ee03d5489483db0b7  Beginning is clear, in Winedt menu Go to Options -> Execution Modes -> PDF Viewer.

Uncheck the Auto-detect checkbox.

Click the top magnifying glass icon.  After that one needs to know where is Sumatra. This is know complicated https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/a-question-about-default-installation-directory/3470

Comment: well you did install sumatra? Then you should know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Options` menu, click on the `Execution modes` submenu. You'll have this window, in which you can choose your main pdf viewer:

[image]